# Does red hat hackers exist?

Tags: redhat

Hello i am searching info about hacking and i found a category that called red hat hackers.

I searching for a couple of hours but i cant find any valiant info...

I have found articles about hackers (white,black,grey,green) but almost none about red hat's .

I also found this 
"A Red Hat hacker is employed by one government to hack and bring down websites and online services of another country." 
But i am not sure if this is the red hat or spy hacker....
Also some claim that this category dosnt exist.

Any help?
thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Red Hat Hacker.

There are following categories of Hackers:

- White hat hacker
- Black hat hacker
- Grey hat hacker
- Script kiddie
- Suicide hacker
- Hacktivist

There may be some other categories but the main ones are listed above.

I think you are confused in RedHat Linux and other categories of Hackers.

RedHat is an organization which has created a Linux OS, known as RedHat.